# Why rewrite(nginx) redirects with 301 code?

Tags: nginx, redirect, rewrite, 301-redirect

I have this configuration:

```
location ~ ^/myway(.*) {
    rewrite ^/myway(.*)$ /anotherway$1;
    rewrite_log on;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/errors notice;
}

location /anotherway {
    ...
    internal;
}
```

url: `site.com/myway/` works fine as it should(rewrites to `site.com/anotherway/`).
But url: `site.com/myway` redirects to `site.com/anotherway/`. Why? Should it give 404 error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change `(.*)` to `(.+)`

> `.*` matches any character (except newline) Quantifier: * Between zero
>   and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed
>   [greedy]
>
> `.+` matches any character (except newline) Quantifier: + Between one
>   and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed
>   [greedy]

That mean :

- `/myway(.*)` match /myway(...) & /myway/(...)
- `/myway(.+)` match /myway/(...) only

> If the specified regular expression matches a request URI, URI is
>   changed as specified in the replacement string. The rewrite directives
>   are executed sequentially in order of their appearance in the
>   configuration file. It is possible to terminate further processing of
>   the directives using flags. If a replacement string starts with
>   “http://” or “https://”, the processing stops and the redirect is
>   returned to a client.

More info on Nginx rewrite : http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite

By the way you can test regular expression here : https://regex101.com/

Comment: Thanks for explanation of this. But why does nginx redirect? Why does it behave this way?

Comment: Because you use `rewrite` http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite

Comment: Still misunderstand. I don't use flag `permanent` or any other.

Comment: Check your rewrite log

Answer (score 0):

Try this - I added a couple of slashes. Not 100% sure it will work but it's worth a try.

```
location ~ ^/myway/(.*) {
  rewrite ^/myway/(.*)$ /anotherway$1;
  rewrite_log on;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/errors notice;
}
```

It could also be related to a try_files somewhere in your config file.